# passenger-config not set ruby version from rvm default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger-nginx

I have upgraded ruby version from 2.3.1 to 3.0.2 and also done related changes.
On server, after deployment, nginx server cant start and giving error for old version.

I have checked ruby version with login user in ubuntu and rvm list , new 3.0.2 version is set as default version.

```
Error log: 
App 7441 stdout:
App 7441 stdout:
[ E 2021-10-19 03:59:51.9761 5027/T49 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/apprunner/application/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: c6399257
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-J6lyAl.html
  Message from application: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:72:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:59:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:61:in `new'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:61:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:173:in `new'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:173:in `to_definition'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:11:in `evaluate'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:24:in `build'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `definition'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:88:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@application/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:456:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:323:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:461:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:322:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ E 2021-10-19 03:59:51.9814 5027/T7 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-25] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is c6399257. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Don't know why error is show version 2.3.0?

How to set ruby version to passenger from rvm?

passenger check ruby command gives two different output:
Command: passenger-config about ruby-command

1. With Sudo user (rvm command not detected):

```html
root@ip-:/usr/bin# passenger-config about ruby-command
    passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
      Command: /usr/bin/ruby2.3
      Version: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
      To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby2.3
      To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.3
      To use with Standalone: /usr/bin/ruby2.3 /usr/bin/passenger start
    The following Ruby interpreter was found first in $PATH:
      Command: /usr/bin/ruby
      Version: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
      To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
      To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby
      To use with Standalone: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/passenger start
```

2. System user(login user where rvm command detected):

```html
current$ passenger-config about ruby-command
Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old, or some wrapper scripts are missing. Please update/regenerate them first by running:
rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvmsudo rvm repair all
If that doesn't seem to work, please run:
rvmsudo rvm wrapper ruby-3.0.2 --no-prefix --all
```

Please provide any clue, how to set passenger ruby default version or how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

As passenger is designed to server multiple (Rails) applications on one webserver, there are config options per virtual host (actually per dirctory) to set the environment for each application.

see https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/apache/ and https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/nginx/

RVM installs wrappers for each installed ruby in i.e. ~/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-3.0.2/ruby and you can tell passenger to use this ruby for your application.

in an apache config, you can write:

```
<Directory "/path/to/you/rails/app">
  PassengerRuby "/home/your-user/.rvm/wrappers/3.0.2/ruby"
  RailsEnv production
</Directory>
```

passenger-config tells you what wrapper to use, but you must set the ruby environment first. My passenger-config outputs this comment:

> ### Notes for RVM users
>
> Do you want to know which command to use for a different Ruby interpreter? 'rvm use' that Ruby interpreter, then re-run 'passenger-config about ruby-command'.